# How build the URL to request the Name of Person in Wikiquote and Chose a Quote (maybe at random) ?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm writing a npm module to get from wikiquote a quote by choosing a famous person, i'm looking a https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query to build the URL to get the right request ! But i can't get the right solution !

Someone can get the explanation of which properties to use in the request ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Wikiquote API does not have structured data about quotes and people.

All of the data is just stored in pages, that could be grouped by [author](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/List_of_people_by_name), [places](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Places), or [more](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Category:Proverbs). You can fetch an HTML version ([for example](https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Umberto_Eco&rvprop=timestamp%7Cuser%7Ccomment%7Ccontent&rvparse=1)) or wikitext version ([for example](https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Umberto_Eco&rvprop=timestamp%7Cuser%7Ccomment%7Ccontent)) of a Wikiquote page, and then try to parse it. It looks like pages regularly use a bulleted list for quotes, so that may provide some parsable  regularity.

Comment: With an HTTP request with these params i can get the JSON choice of persons to chose in :                                                                                                            var params = {
      format: "json",
      action: "opensearch",
      search: "tesla"
    };
    // the options to use to build the right URL for the request
    var options = {
      protocol: 'https',
      hostname : 'en.wikiquote.org',
   pathname:  '/w/api.php',
   query: params
    };